# How can I restore latest backup programmatically?

Tags: sql-server

How can I restore the latest SQL Server backup to a target server programmatically?

We have mixed environment, Azure and on-prem and we need to backup a SQL database in Azure then restore it to an on-prem SQL Server that we use to run the reports.

In Azure environment we have a production SQL Server and we backup one specific database to Azure blob storage, this is done each day at midnight.

Backup file format is `databasename_year-month-day.bak`. Our database is named `scups` therefore our backups are named `scups_2017-11-14.bak`, `scups_2017-11-15.bak` etc. Backups are about 35 Gb in size and they complete within a few minutes.

On-Prem environment:

Windows task scheduler on an on-prem SQL Server Reporting Services runs AZcopy (Azure PowerShell) and SQL backup is downloaded from Azure blob storage to its local disk, this process starts at 1:45 AM and database is downloaded within an hour.

At 5:00 AM restore job on our on-prem reporting server is invoked via SQL Server agent and this restores the database, ready to be used by the people that run the reports.

This process works but problem is, currently we have to modify the SQL Server job every evening so that correct date of database backup is restored.

So, I have to modify the SQL Server job to include specific file, for example we have to replace `scups_2017-11-15.bak` with `scups_2017-11-16.bak` so that latest database backup from 11/16 is restored.

How can I modify the script so that it restores the latest backup each morning?
And, is there a better way to automate this process?

I would appreciate any suggestions.

This is our SQL Server job:

```
USE MASTER 
GO

ALTER DATABASE scups 
SET multi_user WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO

-- Now put it into single user mode and drop it. Use Rollback Immediate to disconnect any -- sessions and rollback their transactions. Safe since you are about to drop the DB.
ALTER DATABASE scups
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO

DROP DATABASE scups
GO
--pause sleep 2 minutes

USE master

RESTORE DATABASE [scups] 
FILE = N'scups_Data',  
FILE = N'ftrow_fulltext_catalog',  
FILE = N'ftrow_CourseForumEntries' 
FROM DISK = N'C:\download\ScupsFullBackup\scups_2017-11-14.bak' 
WITH FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'scups_Data' TO N'U:\data\scups.mdf',  
MOVE N'ftrow_fulltext_catalog' TO N'U:\data\scups1.ndf',  
MOVE N'ftrow_CourseForumEntries' TO N'U:\data\scups2.ndf',  
MOVE N'scups_Log' TO N'L:\logs\scups_log.ldf', 
RECOVERY, REPLACE, STATS = 10
```

Comment: One possibility would be to create a *symbolic link* to your latest backup file, using Windows tools like `mklink`. That way, the *target* of your backup job would always be the same, e.g. `scups_latest.bak`, which in turn would be a symbolic link to the actual, latest `.bak` file. Using MKLINK, you should be able to create this symbolic link a batch file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the name of the backup file is the only variable, you should be able to do something like this:

```
use maintdb;
go

create procedure dbo.restoreScups(@backupFile varchar(4000))
as
begin
ALTER DATABASE scups 
SET multi_user WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO

-- Now put it into single user mode and drop it. Use Rollback Immediate to disconnect any -- sessions and rollback their transactions. Safe since you are about to drop the DB.
ALTER DATABASE scups
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO

DROP DATABASE scups
GO
--pause sleep 2 minutes

USE master

RESTORE DATABASE [scups] 
FILE = N'scups_Data',  
FILE = N'ftrow_fulltext_catalog',  
FILE = N'ftrow_CourseForumEntries' 
FROM DISK = @backupfile 
WITH FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'scups_Data' TO N'U:\data\scups.mdf',  
MOVE N'ftrow_fulltext_catalog' TO N'U:\data\scups1.ndf',  
MOVE N'ftrow_CourseForumEntries' TO N'U:\data\scups2.ndf',  
MOVE N'scups_Log' TO N'L:\logs\scups_log.ldf', 
RECOVERY, REPLACE, STATS = 10;

end
```

Then you can call this procedure from something like powershell like this:
$query = @'
exec maintdb.dbo.restoreScups @backupFile = 'C:\download\ScupsFullBackup\scups_2017-11-14.bak';
@'

```
invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance yourServer -Query $query;
```

Comment: Thank you! That is definitely something I will try to do!